# How to package/run 32-bit application built with VS 2015 using libcef.dll from Spotify

Tags: visual-c++, dll, chromium-embedded, msvcrt

I am trying to build a few different 32-bit C++ applications with Visual Studio 2015 that use CEF. To use CEF, I am currently acquiring the CEF prebuilts from [Spotify](http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html). The dll wrapper for CEF is built using Visual Studio 2015 with some modifications to its CMake files to force it to build with MD and MDd mode regardless of other settings. This was sufficient to make these C++ applications run on some machines. Any machine on which Visual Studio 2015 is installed on before anything else they can run on, however some machines seem to exist in a state such that the program will produce an error on starting when lacking the MSVC 2015 runtime (as expected), but when adding the MSVC 2015 runtime the program simply crashes; however, it only crashes after CEF is used. These programs work fine when they don't link to libcef.dll and don't include the browser functionality.

Upon investigating, I found that libcef.dll, as built by spotify, links to MSVCP110_WIN.DLL, which is from the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable package. Naturally, the application I am building links to MSVCP140.DLL, which is from the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package. This means that the application ultimately links to two runtimes simultaneously. I do not know if this is an issue, but so far it seems to be my best lead. Installing the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable does not change the outcome and it continues to crash when CEF is used.

This issue has been witnessed on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 and the application works without CEF on both of those operating systems as well, so the operating system is not likely to be the cause of the failure on these systems specifically.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and does anyone know a workaround? Also, does anybody know if it is okay to mix these two runtimes and what the limitations are? It seems that the installation history of a given machine affects the success of running the application, so any hints into what combination of things leads to this failure would be helpful as well.

Comment: One tries very hard to *not* mix runtimes, sometimes things just work, sometimes they don't, some they don't work in silent ways with very odd runtime failures later on, makes for interesting debug sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

1. Use the lastest version of VS that will allow a selection of Platform Toolset that matches libdef.dll.  For example, VS2013 **might** allow the selection of the 2012 CRT.
2. Or convince Spotify to rebuild libcef.dll such that it matches your version of CRT
3. Or convince Spotify to **not** release libraries that depend on the CRT (yes that's probably a bit of work).
4. Or make a small app built against the older CRT, this app can then successfully use libcef.dll.  Then you get to use any IPC technique so that your main VS2015 app can talk to this wrapper.  Running out-of-process is one way to segregate the unruly third party libraries.

EDIT:

5. This is open source?  Well good news, you can fix this yourself, built the CEF against your favorite version of VS.

Comment: IPC isn't a reasonable option here because cef is being wrapped into a dockable QWidget (its a QT application) and it would be a bit complicated to get it working here. As for building CEF, I am seriously considering it at this point, but I want to visit any other potential options first.